# What is "Authentication failed" status on network adapter

Tags: windows, networking, ethernet, network-adapter, authentication

I did not know that network adapter can even have status such as "Authentication failed":

[image]

Do you know what is causing this and how it can be resolved?

The network connection through this adapter is working normally. This makes this status information more confusing.

Comment: In the Authentication tab of the Local Area Connection Properties, do you have "Enable IEE 802.1x authentication for this network" checked?

Comment: @Cown – yes, it is checked. Also checkboxes **Remember my credentials** and **Fallback to unauthorized network access** are checked. It is possible that the latter checkbox is causing that network connection works despite the authentication failure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem occurs because the "Enable IEEE 802.1x authentication for this network" is checked under the Authentication tab of the Local Area Connection Properties. When you uncheck these boxes the problem will go away.

Your computer is probably using the 802.1X standard for connecting to some of the networks you use. The 802.1X is an IEEE protocol and a there's a nicely detailed explanation on Network Engineering:
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35750/whats-the-difference-between-radius-and-802-1x-port-based-authentication

Comment: Thank you, I understand that this could help. In my case, the entire adapter properties window is disabled by machine policy. But the authentication has some purpose, or doesn't? It means, even if I could, I cannot simply disable it. It is possible that after disabling, the entire connectivity will fail. Maybe you advice could be good in home networks, where there is no authentication mechanism, but I am afraid in this case the network requires authenticating.

Comment: It's probably because the computer uses the 802.1X standard for connecting to some of the networks you use. The 802.1X is a IEEE protocol and a there's a nicely detailed explanation on Network Engineering: [link](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/35750/whats-the-difference-between-radius-and-802-1x-port-based-authentication)

Comment: I agree with the answer except of point *When you uncheck these boxes the problem will go away.* It is like *When you disable authentication in your system, all those problems with logins will go away.*

Comment: This is useless for WiFi connections that encounter this problem.

Comment: The relevant Windows Service for this is Wired AutoConfig. Disabling that will fix the issue, though it doesn't address the root cause, AFAICT. For Wireless, it *might* be the WLAN AutoConfig service.

Answer (score 0):

It works.  Unselect `Enable IEE 802.1x authentication for this network` from Authentication Tab in Local Area Properties.

Comment: Why does this work?

Answer (score -1):

I changed from Microsoft PEAP to Cisco PEAP and the problem went away.  I can't explain why this resolved the problem for me, but my PC was able to authenticate.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please explain 1) How to do this, and 2) What, if anything, is required in order to do this. For example, is this only available to users connecting to Cisco equipment? Do you need Cisco client software installed? Lacking these details this question is more of a clue than an answer.

Comment: What are these settings/features and where are they located?